# MVC 5 Identity String Id's To Int

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new in MVC 5. When I create MVC 5 project. There is a simple Bootstrap website. And on this sample website, create an account. The program created these tables for me on my DB.

[image]

And when I control this tables data type. All id column's data type is NVARCHAR(128) for GUID. But i want to convert this field to int.

I try change some codes (IdentityUser class, etc.), but these in Microsoft's Dll. So I can't change.

How can i change all string id columns, string to id in MVC Solution? When I create new account on website, automatically must be give int userId not GUID. And also the other tables (Roles,UserRoles) must be have int id.

Thanks.

Comment: Close your VS solution ↠ Open your SQL-server Management Studio ↠ Right-click on the table and choose 'Design' ↠ Click on the text field under 'Data Type' and choose **int** ↠ Right-Click on tables flap and choose Save ↠ You're done..? :p

Comment: :) Yeah, you are right, I can change on SQL like you say. :) But I want, when i create new account on website, automatically must be give int UserId, not Guid type. And also the other tables (Roles,UserRoles) must be have int id.

Comment: Well, have you tried something yet? Stackoverflow is where you ask questions with preferably an approach made.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have to :

-Change the type of the key to int in the Identity user class 
-Add customized Identity classes that use int as key 
-Change the context class and user manager to use int as key 
-Change start-up configuration to use int as key 
-Change the AccountController to pass int as key

[here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)  a link where all steps are explained to achieve this.